# How to plot only one column in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given this simple data I want to plot the equivalent of base

```
plot(dat$value)
```

but with `ggplot`.

```
 dat= structure(list(name = c("Cord", "Cord", 
"amo", "amo", 
 "amo", "ramo"), 
value = c(7, 0.7, 9, 
0.9, 0.8, 0.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried:

```
> ggplot(data = dat) +      geom_point(aes(x = value, colour = name)) 
 Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
 ! geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

I need to plot "count" on y axis vs value on x axis

Comment: you are missing `mapping` in the call: `ggplot(data = res) +      geom_point(mapping=aes(x = value, colour = name))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a row index using `tibble::rownames_to_column`, then use that to plot along the x-axis, so that you get a similar result to `plot(dat$value)`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  rownames_to_column("ind") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ind, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme_bw()
```

**Output**

[image]

Or you can put the function directly into `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(
  x = rownames_to_column(dat)$rowname,
  y = value,
  color = name
)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme_bw()
```

Or another option is to use `row.names`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = as.numeric(row.names(dat)), y = value, colour = name)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not clear. I want to do exactly like "plot(dat$value)" but in ggplot with coloring from name

Comment: @Tpellirn In base R `plot(dat$value)` has an implicit `x` equal to `seq_along(dat$value)`.

Comment: @Tpellirn Oh okay, I did not interpret it that way. I have updated my answer with some other possibilities, but `seq_along` really requires the least amount of code, as shown by @RuiBarradas.

Answer (score 0):

Base R `plot(dat$value)` has an implicit `x` equal to `seq_along(dat$value)`.
Use `x = seq_along(value)` and `y = value`.

```r
dat <- structure(list(name = c("Cord", "Cord", 
                               "amo", "amo", 
                               "amo", "ramo"), 
                      value = c(7, 0.7, 9, 
                                0.9, 0.8, 0.7)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
                 class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = seq_along(value), y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>